# A corollary of the Chernoff bound

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, inequality, proof-writing, solution-verification

During my Statistic course, we were asked the following question:

Let $ X_1, \ldots , X_n $ be a $n$ observations that are i.i.d and assume $ X_i \sim \mathcal{N} (0,\sigma^2) $.
Use the Chernoff Bound, i.e.

$$ \Pr( X \geq t ) \leq \frac{E(e^{\lambda X})}{e^{\lambda t}} $$

And the fact that the Moment Generating Function of
$X_i$ is

$$ M_{X_i} = E(e^{\lambda X_i}) = E(e^{\frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 \lambda^2}) $$

to prove that, for all $ t > 0$

$$ \Pr\left( \frac{1}{n} \sum_i^n X_i \geq t \right) \leq  e^{-n \frac{t^2}{2\sigma^2} } .$$

Using the MGM of the mean, I have:

$$ \Pr\left( \frac{1}{n} \sum_i^n X_i \geq t \right) \leq  \frac{e^{-n^2 \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 \lambda^2 }}{e^{\lambda t}} $$

(If I didn't miscalculate something).

But I can't get any further...

Comment: Ok, I just realized I made a bad mistake in the computation, yet I'm far away from the solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\bar{X}=n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ is normally distributed with $E\bar{X}=0$,  $\text{Var}(\bar{X})=\sigma^2/n$ and moment generating function $Ee^{\lambda \bar{X}}=\exp(\frac{\sigma^2}{2n}\lambda^2)$. In particular for $\lambda>0$, the chernoff bound gives us that
$$
P(\bar{X}\geq t)\le e^{-\lambda t}Ee^{\lambda \bar{X}}=\exp\left(\frac{\sigma^2}{2n}\lambda^2-\lambda t\right);\quad (\lambda>0)\tag{0}
$$
Minimize the left hand side of $0$ over $\lambda>0$ by choosing $\lambda=tn/\sigma^2$ to get that
$$
P(\bar{X}\geq t)\leq \exp\left(\frac{-t^2n}{2\sigma^2}\right)
$$

Comment: Thank you!! Great, I see it now

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$. The Chernoff bound gives that for all positive $\lambda$,
$$
\Pr(X\geqslant t)\leqslant e^{-\lambda t}\mathbb E\left[\exp\left(\lambda X\right)\right].
$$
Using independence, we derive that 
$$
\Pr(X\geqslant t)\leqslant e^{-\lambda t}\prod_{i=1}^n\mathbb E\left[\exp\left(\lambda \frac{X_i}n\right)\right]
$$
and then using the expression for the Laplace transform, 
we end up with 
$$
\Pr(X\geqslant t)\leqslant e^{-\lambda t}\prod_{i=1}^n \exp\left(\frac{\lambda^2\sigma^2}{2n^2}\right) 
$$
or more simply,
$$
\Pr(X\geqslant t)\leqslant  \exp\left(-\lambda t+\frac{\lambda^2\sigma^2}{2n }\right) .
$$
This estimate is valid for all $\lambda$; it then remains to minimize the last term with respect to $\lambda>0$, or equivalently,  $-\lambda t+\frac{\lambda^2\sigma^2}{2n }$.